# Generating Different Files During Angular Build Process

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular project and need to generate different files during the build process based on certain conditions or configurations. I'm looking for guidance on how to achieve this within the Angular framework.

i have use this command `ng build --prod --aot --output-hashing=media --base-href=...` it is not work

Answer (score 1):

You can just have the configuration in your `angular.json` file like this:

```
    "configurations": {
        "production": {
            "fileReplacements": [
                {
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
            ],
            "baseHref": "./",
            "outputHashing": "all",
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "optimization": false,
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "sourceMap": false,
            "namedChunks": true,
            "aot": true
        },
        "development": {
            "fileReplacements": [
                {
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
            ],
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "optimization": false,
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "namedChunks": true
        },
        "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    }
```

and then call them using `ng build --configuration production`.

Inline args require a different approach. For example, `ng build --prod --aot --output-hashing=media --base-href=...` should be: `ng build --configuration production --aot=true --output-hashing=media --base-href ./`. You can find more details on inline args [here](https://angular.io/cli/build)